# What is GPU? Should I have it?

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to install the Boinc Manager.  It fails with the final three lines:

```
Setting up GUI RPC socket
GUI RPC bind to port 31416 failed: 98
gstate.init() failed
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

From simply googling the error, I found this on the BOINC Wiki: [GUI RPC bind to port 31416 failed: 98](https://boinc.mundayweb.com/wiki/index.php?title=GUI_RPC_bind_to_port_31416_failed:_98)

> This error happens when the user has no permission to use the RPC port number, or forgotten to allow it through the firewall.
>   Happens in combination with [Gstate.init() failed, error code: -180](https://boinc.mundayweb.com/wiki/index.php?title=Gstate.init()_failed,_error_code:_-180)
>
> To set BOINC to use a specific port number, one different from the default 31316, do:
>   `boinc --gui_rpc_port N`, **example given** `boinc --gui_rpc_port 37777`, this starts the BOINC client with TCP port 37777.
>
> If you don't want to use any GUI to check on this BOINC from a remote location, you can also start BOINC without any GUI RPC:
>   `boinc --no_gui_rpc`

The page for [Gstate.init() failed, error code: -180](https://boinc.mundayweb.com/wiki/index.php?title=Gstate.init()_failed,_error_code:_-180) also says:

> This is a permission problem under Linux, where the user has forgotten to add an RPC port with which to connect to the graphical user interface, or has no permission to use this port.

This seems to be a networking issue - nothing to do with the GPU.